# NSFetchedResultsController with sections sorted by TWO criteria

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view that displays a musician's albums.  Each section is an Album, each row is a Track.  I need the albums/sections sorted by release date, then by title.  I'm pulling the tracks from Core Data like so:

```
fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
...
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"album.releaseDate" ascending:YES],
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"album.title" ascending:YES],
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"trackNumber" ascending:YES],
                                nil];
frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:context
                                            sectionNameKeyPath:@"album.releaseDate" // <-- PROBLEM HERE
                                                     cacheName:nil];
```

This doesn't work because two albums with the same release date will appear in the same section.

If I use album.title as the sectionNameKeyPath, hell breaks loose because the sections are sorted alphabetically, then imposed on the tracks (which are sorted by date, title, trackNumber).

How do I sort the sections by date, then by title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, this single-property sorting is just something we have to live with on iOS.  So I added a transient property to Album that acts as a sort key for both properties:

```
- (NSString *)sortKeyDateTitle
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sortKeyDateTitle"];
    NSString *sortKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.releaseDate, self.title];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sortKeyDateTitle"];
    return sortKey;
}
```

It produces strings like this:

```
1954-04-01 06:00:00 +0000A Night At Birdland, Vol. 1
1954-04-01 06:00:00 +0000A Night At Birdland, Vol. 2
```

It works, but converting from date to string **for sorting** seems stupid.  I'm waiting for something better.

Comment: did you find a way to sort sections by TWO properties?